# How to tag friends on comment with new facebook update (29 Sep 2013) by Facebook API C#

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, comments

I have developed a desktop application to tag friends on comment via `Facebook API C#`. It worked perfectly until Facebook had new update in 28 or 29 Sept, don't remember exactly, then it does not work right now. I use format `@[fb_user_id:fb_name]` to tag friend. However, Facebook will replace that string by an empty string in new update. Who knows what's new format or how to tag friend on comment by graph api.

Answer (score 0):

this how to tag friend on status.

```
 protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblPost.Text = txtPost.Text;
    var client = new FacebookClient("tokenHere");
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                { 
                     { "message", "your status here" },
                     {"tags" , "friend id here, only number"},
                     {"place" , "place ID, only number"}
                };

    client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
    lblPost.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lblPost.Text = "Status Updated!";
}
```